# Is it possible to replace one marker using gmaps4rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

Using Gmaps.map.replaceMarkers() I can replace entire marker set. But in my application I will use more than 3000 markers.

How to replace one marker or subset of markers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely possible but because there is no rule, there is custom code to write.

Here is how I proceed generally:

- I [add some custom data in the marker's json](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Controller), the `id` of the active record's object generally
- I sort my markers client side in javascript variables, say you have the ids of markers you want to remove in a js array called `toClear`
- I remove useless markers:

Coffeescript:

```
for marker in Gmaps.map.markers
  if marker.id in toClear
    Gmaps.map.clearMarker marker
```

- I add the new one `Gmaps.addMarkers new_markers_array`

Comment: The markers are cleared without problems, but when I use Gmaps.map.addMarkers, it seems that all markers is added to the map again (not only submitted). The coffeescript:
https://github.com/denispeplin/mapped-monitor/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/points.js.coffee

Comment: I will fix this little bug soon, there is on line to change in the js. I have a pull request here: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/pull/173

Comment: I checked the addMarkers code and though that the reason of duplication is: "this.markers = this.markers.concat(new_markers);", but then I found, that using create_markers does not solve the issue.

Comment: Just use the correction suggested in the pull request, it's fine.

Comment: I just tried this correction. Now other markers are not affected, but the marker, that passed to addMarkers, is added to the list (<ul id="markers_list"></ul>) every time addMarkers called. Is this ok? Maybe it s just how markers_list works, and markers actually is not duplicated?

Comment: Indeed I'd like to clean up/ rewrite much of the codebase. And it's part of the corrections I want to do. Now I'm simply stuck to have a sustainable setup where guard watches jasmine specs as well as the rspec ones at the root of the gem. There is an issue on jasminerice on this subject but no answer so far.

Comment: Please file an issue on github so that I won't forget.

Comment: I opened the issue, hope that it is correct:
[link](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/issues/182). And thank you for answering my question!